# How does one convert a tree like nested data structure of arrays and objects into a list of items with computed/counted id's and tracked parent id's?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, data-structures, mapping

An API returns a nested data structure of arrays and objects. The data comes as a list of tree like objects, each with a possible parent-child relationship. The structure itself is shown by the following example code.

```
[{
  label: "search me",
  value: "searchme",
  children: [{

    label: "search me too",
    value: "searchmetoo",
    children: [{

      label: "No one can get me",
      value: "anonymous",
    }],
  }],
}, {
  label: "search me2",
  value: "searchme2",
  children: [{

    label: "search me too2",
    value: "searchmetoo2",
    children: [{

      label: "No one can get me2",
      value: "anonymous2",
    }],
  }],
}]
```

The above data has to be converted into a (flat) array of objects where each object will represent a former node element but with a unique primary key (id). Also a node's parent-id equals its parent's id (the primary key) except for root nodes that do not have a parent, and therefore the parent-id then should be null.

The target structure of the above provided source data then matches the following code ...

```
[{
  id: 1,                // DIAGID
  parentId: null,       // PARENTID
  label: "search me",   // DIAGNOSIS
  value: "searchme"     // DIAGTYPE
}, {
  id: 2,
  parentId: 1,
  label: "search me too",
  value: "searchmetoo"
}, {
  id: 3,
  parentId: 2,
  label: "No one can get me",
  value: "anonymous"
}, {
  id: 4,
  parentId: null,
  label: "search me2",
  value: "searchme2"
}, {
  id: 5,
  parentId: 4,
  label: "search me too2",
  value: "searchmetoo2"
}, {
  id: 6,
  parentId: 5,
  label: "No one can get me2",
  value: "anonymous2"
}]
```

Comment: Try using JSON.parse on the json data, you may get the desired result.

Comment: That is not JSON.

Comment: parsing by itself with solve nothing on this cause thanks for the comment @Ankan Bag

Comment: The conversion you speak of seems to do a lot more: none of the properties match with anything in the input. Please provide a consistent pair of input/output

Comment: JSON does not have single quoted string literals. You'll have to update again. But more importantly, if you really get JSON, you'll have to parse  it. My assumption is that you get an object, not JSON. Better rephrase that. Also your title says you want JSON as output? Are you sure? I guess you want a JavaScript array, not JSON (which is a text format).

Comment: please add consistent data of source and target data. what have you tried and what does not work?

Comment: @layth ... Regarding the heavily edited original post and all the provided different approaches/solutions, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a recursive method for [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and store `parent` for the next call.

This approach increments `id` for all nodes.

```js
const
    flatTree = (id => parent => ({ children = [], ...object }) => [
        { id: ++id, ...object, parent },
        ...children.flatMap(flatTree(id))
    ])(0),
    tree = [{ label: 'search me', value: 'searchme', children: [{ label: 'search me too', value: 'searchmetoo', children: [{ label: 'No one can get me', value: 'anonymous' }] }] }, { label: 'four', searchme: '4four' }],
    flat = tree.flatMap(flatTree(null));

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @PeterSeliger, sorry. please see edit.

Comment: Nice, and `flatMap(flatTree(/* ... */))` lately became a branding approach of yours, as much as I seem to reduce everything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive function `dfs` that performs a pre-order traversal through the input tree, and passes along a counter that feeds the `id` property that will be used in the output. Also the current node's `id` is passed as `parentId` to the recursive call:

```js
const dfs = (children, counter={id: 1}, parentId=null) =>
    children.flatMap(({children=[], ...node}) => [{ 
        ...counter, 
        parentId,
        ...node
    }].concat(dfs(children, counter, counter.id++)));

const response = [{label: "search me",value: "searchme",children: [{label: "search me too",value: "searchmetoo",children: [{label: "No one can get me",value: "anonymous",}],}],}, {label: "search me2",value: "searchme2",children: [{label: "search me too2",value: "searchmetoo2",children: [{label: "No one can get me2",value: "anonymous2",}],}],}];
const result = dfs(response);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The FP purist in me is a little sickened by that mutable parameter, but damn, this is slick!

Comment: I don't know if your code was in response to an earlier edit of the question, but the input is (now) and array of items like your input.

Comment: Yes, my code was in response to an earlier version of the question, where input was not an array. Now updated (too late of course -- busy day).

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say a recursive tree walk is all you need, but you can accomplish the same thing easily with a generator:

```js
function *visitNodes( root, parent = null, id = 0 ) {
  
  const node = {
    ...root,
    id : ++id,
    parentId = parent ? parent.id : null
  };
  delete node.children;
  
  yield node;
  
  for ( const child of root.children ?? [] ) {
    yield *visitNodes(child, node, id);
  }
  
}
```

Having defined the generator, you can either iterate over the nodes:

```js
for (const node of visitNodes( tree ) ) {
  // do something useful with node here
}
```

You can convert it into a list easily, either with the spread operator:

```js
const nodes  = [...visitNodes(tree)];
```

or by using `Array.from()`:

```js
const nodes = Array.from( visitNodes(tree) );
```

Comment: first think i think you meant  parentId: parent ? parent.id : null

if there is no children you will get   
TypeError: root.children is not iterable

Comment: @layth — I'm assuming that leaf nodes have an empty `children` array. But... code changed to deal with the case where `children` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

A single recursively implemented [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)er functionality which maps and collects any item generically does the job.

It utilizes a `collector` object as the [`reduce` method's 2nd argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters) (and the reducer's initial value). The `collector`'s `result` array collects any item. And `count` gets incremented constantly and assigned as a collected item's `id` (former `DIAGID`) whereas an item's `parentId` (former `PARENTID`) gets updated as needed in order to always reflect the current recursive call stack ...

```js
function countMapAndCollectNestedItemRecursively(collector, item) {

  let { count = 0, parentId = null, result } = collector;
  const { children = [], ...itemRest } = item;

  result.push({

    id: ++count,
    parentId,

    ...itemRest,
  });
  count = children.reduce(

    countMapAndCollectNestedItemRecursively,
    { count, parentId: count, result }

  ).count;

  return { count, parentId, result };
}

const sampleData = [{
  label: "FOO",
  value: "foo",
  children: [{

    label: "FOO BAR",
    value: "fooBar",
    children: [{

      label: "FOO BAR BAZ",
      value: "fooBarBaz",
    }],
  }, {
    label: "FOO BIZ",
    value: "fooBiz",
    children: [{

      label: "FOO BIZ BUZ",
      value: "fooBizBuz",
    }],
  }],
}, {
  label: "BAR",
  value: "bar",
  children: [{

    label: "BAR BAZ",
    value: "barBaz",
    children: [{

      label: "BAR BAZ BIZ",
      value: "barBazBiz",
      children: [{

        label: "BAR BAZ BIZ BUZ",
        value: "barBazBizBuz",
      }],
    }, {
      label: "BAR BAZ BUZ",
      value: "barBazBuz",
    }],
  }, {
    label: "BAR BIZ",
    value: "barBiz",
    children: [{

      label: "BAR BIZ BUZ",
      value: "barBizBuz",
    }],
  }],
}];

console.log(
  sampleData.reduce(

    countMapAndCollectNestedItemRecursively,
    { result: [] },

  ).result
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This version is something of a mash-up of ideas from trincot and Nicholas Carey.  From trincot's answer (which actually answers a different, but closely related question) I steal his `{ctr: id: 1}` handling.  And from Nicholas, I use the generator to iterate through the values more easily, although I simplify a bit from there.

I think they combine to give a nice solution:

```js
const flatten = function * (xs, ctr = {id: 1}, parent = null) {
  for (let {children = [], ...x} of xs) {
    const node = {id: ctr .id ++, parentId: parent ? parent .id : null, ...x}
    yield node
    yield * flatten (children, ctr, node)
  }
}

const transform = (xs) => [...flatten (xs)]

const response = [{label: "search me", value: "searchme", children: [{label: "search me too", value: "searchmetoo", children: [{label: "No one can get me", value: "anonymous"}]}]}, {label: "search me2", value: "searchme2", children: [{label: "search me too2", value: "searchmetoo2", children: [{label: "No one can get me2", value: "anonymous2"}]}]}]

console .log (transform (response))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: I like this one pretty much. And besides the three different base techniques used by You, Nina/trincot and me, the similarity of some implemented details is not that surprising in the end.